# Match Link and Title Between Text Optionally If Exists in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match optional link/title when exists, if there is no link simply match text inside   tags.

Table Example:

```
$html_data = <<<HTML
    <table>
     <tr> <td> Some text here </td> </tr>
     <tr> <td> Some text with link <a href="http://domain1.com/">Link Title 1</a> </td> </tr>
     <tr> <td> Some text here without link </td> </tr>
     <tr> <td> Some text with link <a href="http://domain2.com/">Link Title 2</a> and more text </td> </tr>
    </table>
HTML;
```

Code Example:

```
preg_match_all('~<tr> <td> (?:<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>)? (.*?) </td> </tr>~i', $html_data, $result);
```

So I need grab plain text and link+title if exists and put it in array.

Something like this, when link exists;

```
'text_before' => 'Some text with link'
'link_href' => 'http://domain2.com/'
'link_title => 'Link Title 2'
'text_after' => 'and more text'
```

If there is no link simply match available text between "td" tags.

Something like this, when there is no link;

```
'text' => 'Some text here without link'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start with some steps along the way:

1. `<td.*?<\/td>` as You need a lines with code to evaluate, then:
2. `<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>` as You need a title of the link, then:
3. `href=\"(.*?)\"` as You need a link, then:
4. `<td>(.*?)<` as You need a text, even if there is no link inside, and:
5. `<\/a>(.*?)<` in the end.

Hope it helps.
Cheers.

Edit:
One regex `<td.*?>(.*?)(<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)</a>)?(.*?)</td>`

Comment: No I need one line regex. Match link and title if exists and add to array with text. If there is no link simply match plain text. I'm just not sure how to use optional group matching for links if there is none.

Comment: I will make one regex for You shortly. It's that just sometimes HTML syntax vary so much, that its much better to do some steps. Be right back.

Comment: The above did not work for me, but ones I edited like this
<td> (.*?) (<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>)? (.*?) </td> It worked :-)
Thank you! So it looks like I needed to wrap link around with ( )? for it to be optional.

Comment: Good to see happy face. :D In the code I've put extra parts in case that You don't have as clean code as You posted. Cheers.